# Why is there nothing like PgBouncer for Mongo?

Tags: mongodb, connection-pooling

I lately had a production Mongo cluster which ended operation as too many applications connected to it. The application has a bad design and each application instance allocates a large pool of connections, but I came to wonder that there is nothing like [PgBouncer](https://www.pgbouncer.org/) or [Pgpool](https://www.pgpool.net) which mitigate this for PostgreSQL.

Does somebody know why there is nothing like this middleware for Mongo? Does it have architecture reasons, or is it something else?

Comment: Mongo has quite thick client, which is aware of the server's topology and open connections to all members of replica set. It would be tricky to  put a load balancer in between. Connection pool is configured on the application level, and max total number in db config serverside.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more what "fat" client mean in this context?

Comment: Well, considering how easily you renamed thick clients to fat, I reckon you are familiar with the concept. Anyway, https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/main/src/sdam/server_selection.ts is an example of server selection logic on the client. Mongo clients are responsible not only to pick what connection to use, maintain a pool of connections, measure latency, but also to generate unique ObjectId, keep sessions for causal consistency and plenty of other things.  SQL clients in contrast are basically enhanced telnets synchronously working within single connection.

Comment: Thanks, that cleared things up. Then either I create a new question or may change this one -> What is then the solution to “limited” rouge agents aka clients from draining the instance if they do not know how to handle this power appropriate? Assuming I have no influence on the client but only manage the instance.

Comment: That would be a real good question.  I would define "clients" more specifically - an IP (to limit number of connections from specific host), a login (to limit number of connections per authorised user). I could thinks about some tactical solutions like re-purposing mongos as a proxy,  but am interested if anyone has a proper solution.

Comment: @AlexBlex I would keep this open, but my personal perspective would be "operator of the database" - so how to limit the developers harming a shared instance

Comment: Yeah, I see the point and I do believe it can evolve into feature request when shaped properly. Please factor in perception of the question. Asking about "functionality like in XXX" is a bit vague and significantly limits number of people who can answer the question as they must be familiar with both tools.

Answer (score 0):

The mongobetween is a proxying connections for mongodb.
It is developed by coinbase.

Its architecture was described in the Coinbase technical documents. [https://www.coinbase.com/blog/scaling-connections-with-ruby-and-mongodb#:~:text=%60-,mongobetween,-%60%20is%20written%20in](https://www.coinbase.com/blog/scaling-connections-with-ruby-and-mongodb#:%7E:text=%60-,mongobetween,-%60%20is%20written%20in)

And here is the github link https://github.com/coinbase/mongobetween.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34625525)